# Calculating clockwise/anti-clockwise angles from a point

Tags: geometry, vectors

I'm currently trying to work out if an angle is a clockwise or anti-clockwise rotation about a point. I used the equation: a.b = ||a|| ||b|| cos(A) to calculate the angle between the two vectors in 3D space, but I'm now unsure as to how to tackle the clockwise/anti-clockwise problem and would really appreciate some help on how to approach it.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: If you're working in 3-dimensions clockwise and anti-clockwise depend on where you are looking at the problem from.

Comment: It would be a rotation about the x-axis since the orientation of the fixed point will be standard (with the y always pointing up, x pointing along the edge and z pointing down it e.g: http://i1213.photobucket.com/albums/cc464/Jullith/04_rotation_problem_zpse528d717.png if that makes sense)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In three dimensions, this requires a choice of orientation of the plane $P$ spanned by ${\bf a}, {\bf b}$. We can specify such an orientation by choosing a vector $\bf n$ transverse to $P$; then, the basis (${\bf a}, {\bf b}$) is positively oriented with respect to the orientation---equivalently, the angular displacement from $\bf a$ to $\bf b$ is anticlockwise from the p.o.v. of the endpoint of $\bf n$---if
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} {\bf a} & {\bf b} & {\bf n} \end{pmatrix} > 0$$
and the reverse is true, and in particular the displacement is clockwise, if
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} {\bf a} & {\bf b} & {\bf n} \end{pmatrix} < 0.$$

NB in two dimensions, there is a conventional choice of orientation of the plane, and if we write ${\bf a} = (a_1, a_2)^T$ and ${\bf b} = (b_1, b_2)^T$, then we have
$$\det \begin{pmatrix} {\bf a} & {\bf b} \end{pmatrix} = a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1 > 0$$
if the displacement is anticlockwise and the reverse inequality if it is clockwise.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm still slightly confused but it does make a bit more sense now. If I were to visualise it, would it look something like this then: http://i1213.photobucket.com/albums/cc464/Jullith/05_rotation_problem_zpsc7f3c626.png

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the picture you should have in mind. The only difference between what you've written in the image is that your matrix is the transpose of mine, but this is no trouble, as taking a transpose doesn't change the determinant.

Comment: (Actually, as I "see" the vectors, $\bf a$ and $\bf b$ should be reversed, but this isn't a problem provided you "see" them the "other" way.)

Answer (score 0):

3D version is covered by Travis and tells you that in 3D you need 3 vectors to define orientation. All you can tell is the vector $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ (there isn't just $+$ and $-$ but entire space of 3D vectors that encodes the orientation of a plane defined by the two vectors).

In 2D:

The dot product gives you the cosine. The cross product (2D equivalent which gives you a pseudo-scalar) gives you the sine. Together they define the angle.

$$\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=|a||b|\cos\alpha$$
$$\vec{a}\times\vec{b}=|a||b|\sin\alpha$$
where $\times$ should be interpreted as the 3rd component of the 3D version. In other terms:

$$a_x b_x+a_yb_y=|a||b|\cos\alpha$$
$$a_x b_y-a_y b_x=|a||b|\sin\alpha$$

Or, if you are willing to use complex numbers, you just remember that dividing complex numbers subtracts the arguments. Representing the $2D$ vectors as complex numbers, you get
$$\cos\alpha+{\rm i}\sin\alpha=e^{i\alpha}=\frac{b/|b|}{a/|a|}$$